# Integer into textview

Tags: java, android

I'm not too experienced with java programming in Android Studio yet, but I couldn't find a solution for this problem:

I want to be able to get 2 integers and convert them into text to put them into a line of text.
So for example:

```
int counterT = 0;
TextView showValueT;

public void CountIncT (View view) {
showValueT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countT);

counterT++;
showValueT.setText(Integer.toString(counterT));
```

Together with the other counter, say `CountIncU / showValueU / countU / counterU`, I want to get a textline that gets the 2 scores and put them together to a textline like:
`(counterT + " - " + counterU)` or 5 - 3 for example, after pressing a button.

I think that I'm just missing a single piece, but I couldn't find it anywhere so I hope that you can help me out here, thanks!

Comment: The line of code that you wrote as an example. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, however it says that is a problem from java.lang.String to int?

Comment: Also, it's suggested that `findViewById` is done in onCreate, not within any view click events. Currently, every time you click the view, you are re-finding the view again and again

Comment: Could you post the whole code?

Comment: what do you mean? `counterT + " - " + counterU` returns a string. You call setText on that. Regardless, setText also accepts an integer value for a string resource